# how to write a mutiple folders makefile

Tags: makefile

I need a Makefile can be used to build a project with this kind of structure :
Multiple source folders.
all objects in a output dir.
Multiple corresponding target folders for object and dependency files.

```
│─inc
└─src
│  ├─lib1
│  │  ├─inc
│  │  └─src
│  ├─lib2
│  │  ├─inc
│  │  └─src
│  └─main.c
│
└─output
       └─src
           ├─lib1
           │  └─src
           │       ├─ lib1_file1.o
           │       └─ lib1_file2.o
           ├─lib2
           │  └─src
           │       ├─ lib2_file1.o
           │       └─ lib2_file2.o
           └─main.o
```

I tried this one, but not work.

```
LIBNAME=libhello.a
OUTDIR=output

CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -MD -O2 -c

LFLAGS = 
INCS =    -Iinc         \
         -Isrc/lib1/inc \
         -Isrc/lib2/inc

SOURCES = src/main.c            \
          src/lib1/lib1_file1.c \
          src/lib1/lib1_file2.c \
          src/lib2/lib2_file1.c \
          src/lib2/lib2_file2.c

OBJS=$(SOURCES:%.c=${OUTDIR}/%.o)

all: ${LIBNAME}

${LIBNAME}: ${OBJS}
    ar crs ${OUTDIR}/$@ $^

.PYONY: clean
clean:
    @rm -rf ${OUTDIR}

${OUTDIR}/%.o:%.c
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @${CC} ${CFLAGS} ${INCS} $< -o $@ ${LFLAGS}
```

Comment: Please specify what exactly does not work, i.e what the expected and actual output is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your makefile will work correctly if you give it the correct source paths. You gave it this:

```
SOURCES = ... src/lib1/lib1_file1.c ...
```

but the actual path in your directory structure is:

```
SOURCES = ... src/lib1/src/lib1_file1.c ...
```